# shadow in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create this type of cell shadow and border, But I'm not getting exactly this type of shadow view. Need Help!

**UICollectionViewCell Class:**

```
class CharacterCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var imageView            : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var checkMarkImageView   : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var shadowLayer   : UIView!

var data: String = "" {
    didSet{
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: data)
        
        shadowLayer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        shadowLayer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shadowLayer.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        shadowLayer.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        shadowLayer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        contentView.layer.borderWidth  = 2
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    }
}

}
```

**And cellForRow**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CharacterCell
    cell.data = images[indexPath.row]
    
    
    return cell
}
```

**MY OUTPUT:**

[image]

**AND this is What I need:**

[image]

Comment: It seems you have to change shadowLayer frame a bit: bottom 4 pixels lower, height 4 or 2 pixels higher, let 1 or 2 pixels less, width 2 or 4 pixels more. Could you try it ?,

Comment: @claude31 How, using UIBezierPath??

Comment: Yes, you could do it in draw of the UIView. But what you get seems pretty close to what you expect, with just small changes. I would first try it. For a BezierPath, create a path let cellRect : CGRect // set it to the cell frame ; let linePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cellRect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width:30, height: 30)); then   set color as needed         UIColor.gray.setFill()
            linePath.lineWidth = 2
            linePath.stroke()